# trying to build gcc-4.7.2 on CentOS 6, rpath is not find my shared library

Tags: linux, gcc

The following compilation command line fails with the included "no such file" error:

```
/tmp/test/gcc-4.7.2-build_dir/./gcc/xgcc
    -B/tmp/test/gcc-4.7.2-build_dir/./gcc/
    -B/tmp/test/4.7.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bin/
    -B/tmp/test/4.7.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/
    --with-cloog-lib=/usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.7.2/lib64
    -Wl,-rpath=/tmp/test/4.7.2/lib
    -B/tmp/test/4.7.2/lib
    -isystem /tmp/test/4.7.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/include
    -isystem /tmp/test/4.7.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/sys-include
    -c -g -O2  conftest.c

/tmp/test/gcc-4.7.2-build_dir/./gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libcloog-ppl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I include the runtime library path during the build for gcc-4.7.2

Comment: I would like to avoid exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I would like to not build in static libraries. I would like to use the dynamic libraries as they are supposed to be used.  does rpath work for building gcc-4.7.2?

Comment: You don't need to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH permanently, you need it to build your stuff. An alternative that *could possibly* work is to add -Wl,-rpath-link=/path/to/your/libs flag (no guarantee),.

Comment: rpath is already included. the build fails in spite of including rpath

Comment: Pay attention, -rpath-link is different from -rpath.

Comment: in the process of building gcc, it is found that gcc itself needs to resolve runtime dependencies. Not wanting to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, compiling with either rpath or rpath-link appears to be ignored. I still get the 'shared library' error.  Has anyone successfully implemented rpath during the gcc compilation?

Comment: OK let's take it offline, what's your idsid?

Comment: what is the idsid??

Comment: idsid is your unix username @intel. work email is OK too.